# Can Occur center the found text in the buffer?

Tags: occur

When selecting an item from the occur buffer, the highlighted line is at the very bottom of the visible screen. This is less useful than having it 25-50% of the way down the screen(so it's easy to read the text around the found line). Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see the behavior that you describe, at all.  For me, when I choose an occurrence in buffer `*Occur*` it visits the occurrence in the source buffer, putting that smack in the middle of the source-buffer window (vertically).

But if you see what you describe, then just put some window-recentering code on **`occur-mode-find-occurrence-hook`**.

Something like this.  You can use any comparison condition you like. Here, I used "within 10 lines of the top or bottom", but you could use percentages etc.

```el
(defun foo ()
  (let ((line   (line-number-at-pos)))
    (cond ((<= line (+ (line-number-at-pos (window-start)) 10))
           (recenter 10))
          ((>= line (- (line-number-at-pos (window-end)) 10))
           (recenter -10)))))

(add-hook 'occur-mode-find-occurrence-hook 'foo)
```

Comment: Yup, that'll do it.  I get OP's behavior, FWIW.

Comment: Strange that I do not, then.  `emacs -Q` on MS Windows 7. Any hits I click (or use `RET` on) in the occur buffer are shown centered vertically in the source buffer.

Comment: You're right, `emacs -Q` (on Linux) gives the behavior you describe.  Something must be buried somewhere is the setup.